# Prove $D=${$x\in B:x\cap y=x$ for any $y\in A$} is the empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$A=\{\emptyset,\Bbb Z,\Bbb Q\},\\ B=\{\{\emptyset\},\Bbb Z,\Bbb Q\},\\ C=\{x\in B:x\cap y=x\text{ for some }y\in A\},\\ D=\{x\in B:x\cap y=x\text{ for any }y\in A\}.$$

I have to prove whether $D$ is the empty set. But I'd like to ask what's the difference between 'some' and 'any'? What is the difference when I want to proof whether set $C$, $D$ is empty or not?

Am I right to say that there are exactly $2$ elements in $C$, which are $\Bbb Z,\Bbb Q$?

Comment: Any can sometimes mean "some" and sometimes mean "all", and it's sometimes hard to make which one is meant. In this case, since the set $C$ is explicitly given with "some", it is clear from context that "any" is to be interpreted as "all".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between "some" and "any" is this:

> There exists a person $x$ such that $x$ is shorter than me

is a true statement, but

> For any person $x$, $x$ is shorter than me

is not a true statement (I am not the tallest person in the world).

---

In other words, the difference is the same as the difference between the quantifiers $\forall$ and $\exists$.

---

> Am I right to say that there are exactly $2$ elements in $C$, which are $\Bbb Z,\Bbb Q$?

Well, let's see.

**Is $\mathbb  Z\in C$?**

Well, we know that $x\in C\iff x\cap y=x\text{ for some }y\in A$, right? OK, that means $\mathbb Z\in C \iff \mathbb Z\cap y=\mathbb Z\text{ for some }y\in A$.

Now, does there exist some $y\in A$ such that $\mathbb Z\cap y=\mathbb Z$? **Yes, there does!** We can take $y=\mathbb Q$ and get $\mathbb Z\cap \mathbb Q = \mathbb Z$, which proves that $\mathbb Z\in C$.

**Is $\mathbb Q\in C$**?

Well, let's see. As above, we have $\mathbb Q\in C$ if and only if there exists some $y\in A$ such that $\mathbb Q\cap y = \mathbb Q$. Again, we can take $y=\mathbb Q$, and get $\mathbb Q\cap y=\mathbb Q\cap\mathbb Q=\mathbb Q$, proving that $\mathbb Q\in C$.

So, in conclusion, both $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Z$ are in $C$!

**Is $\{\emptyset\}\in C$?**

Here, the answer shall be no. Whatever $y\in A$ we take, we will get $\{\emptyset\}\cap y=\emptyset\neq\{\emptyset\}$, so the condition for $\{\emptyset\}$ to be an element of $C$ is not fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

'$x \cap y = x$ for some $y \in A$' means 'there is an $y \in A$ such that $x \cap y = x$'. That is, $x \cap \emptyset = x$ or $x \cap {\mathbb Z} = x$ or $x \cap {\mathbb Q} = x$.

'$x \cap y = x$ for any $y \in A$' means 'for all $y \in A$ it holds that $x \cap y = x$'. That is, $x \cap \emptyset = x$ and $x \cap {\mathbb Z} = x$ and $x \cap {\mathbb Q} = x$.